# Trying to do Unwind and Create New Relationship Between Nodes Neo4J C# Client

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

I have a list of nodes - In the code as `targetNodeList` and I have a node called `sourceNode`(Different Types Of Nodes).

The List and the single node are already existing in the neo4j Db
and I would like to make a relationship between them with additional data that is inside the `targetNodeList`.

`TargetNodeList` is a wrapper which contains the node data and the relationship data that I would like to put inside the Relationship

I havn't manage to finish the code because I don't know how to continue it but thats the sample that I tried to do :

```
    public void CreateRelationshipBetweenNodes(NodeType sourceNode,List<TargetNodes> targetNodeList,int solutionId)
    {
        graphClient.Cypher
            .Unwind(targetNodeList, "singleNode")
            .Match("(firstNode:FirstType)", "(secondNode:SecondType)")
            .Where(" firstNode.Id = otherNode:FirstType{Id:innerNode.Id}")
            .AndWhere(" secondNode.Id = node:SecondType {Id:singleNode.Id}")
            .WithParams(new { innerNode = sourceNode})
            .Create("(firstNode)-[msg:SENT {solution}]->(secondNode)")
            .WithParam("solution", solutionId).ExecuteWithoutResults();
    }
```

its not working and there is still more data that I want to add to the relationship from the `singleNode` for example: `singleNode.Score`

Would appriciate any help.
Thanks a lot from advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm a little confused with the nodes you're taking in and how they relate, but hopefully the below query will get you on the right route.

First off, match on the `sourceNode` then `UNWIND` your other nodes, ready to do the create. Once you have the two nodes `MATCH`ed you then `CREATE` the relationship (PS. you may want `MERGE` if you don't want duplicates) - and I set an `Id` property on the relationship - you need to provide a property name, else it won't work!

```
graphClient.Cypher
    .Match("(sourceNode:SourceNodeType {Id:sourceNode.Id})")
    .Unwind(targetNodeList, "singleNode")
    .Match("(targetNodeInDb:TargetNode {Id:targetNode.Id})")
    .Create("(sourceNode)-[:SENT {Id:{solutionIdParam}}]->(targetNode)")
    .WithParam("solutionIdParam", solutionId)
    .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

Comment: Really helped alot thank you very much  !  working perfectly !